# How to set cmd commands so they always have some switches turned on?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

To illustrate on an example; instead of `dir` I want every time to show `dir/od` (sort by last modified).

How can I make `dir` *behave* like this without typing `/od` switch every time?

I know of doskey; is there any other way?

EDIT: I'm not looking for just `dircmd`, but a way for other commands as well ... `rd /s` for example.

Comment: You could try this suggestion and include the switches, but you may get a collision if you reuse a name lie 'dir' or something. http://www.unix.com/302235876-post4.html

Comment: You should have chosen a different example, because now everyone is going to tell you about `dircmd` and forget that that was only one example.  ☺

Comment: @JdeBP - good point!

Comment: Sadly, there only seems to be variables for `dir`, `copy`, and `move` (`dircmd` and `copycmd` respectively). There is no `forcmd` despite—perhaps *because of*?—the complexity of the `for` command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an environment variable called `DIRCMD` and set the value to the switches you want.

To test it, at a command prompt type `SET DIRCMD=/OD`. To make it permanent, setup the varible in the system properties.

Comment: "DIRCMD" ... that works for other commands as well, e.g. "COPYCMD" and alike?

Comment: `COPYCMD` will work too. Other commands you will have to test...from a `CMD` prompt type `COMMANDNAME /?` to see what your options are.

Comment: Okey, two bad examples ... but I got the point.

Comment: @Idigas Unfortunately, there is no universal method.